Assigning character specific values to many variables utilizing a loop JavaScript
I am trying to figure out a way to assign tile values to my tictactoe cell variables equivalent to the variable characters themselves in a more concise manner. Each variable should be equivalent to get.elementById("variable name here. i.e. a2").value; I feel there is a better way than to write a verbose code block assigning the values individually and would like to understand this better conceptually if it is even possible.
Note I would like to run these through a loops to assign each variable its own independent value according to the element ID. So tiles.a1 = get.elementById("a1").value;
Here is the small snippet of source code that im building:
var tiles = new Object(); tiles.assignTile = new function() { tiles.a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3 = ''; }
I am currently at the learning stage of basic programming concepts so please elaborate on your response to help me understand better. In the meantime I will scavenge google :)
Hope to hear some bright ideas!
Thanks!

Don't use separate variables, use an array.

You don't use new function() to define functions. It's just function()

You can create a constructor function to initialize your object. Note that obj.prop and obj[prop] are equivalent. Look at the example.


function myTitles() { //constructor function
  for (var i = 0, arg; arg = arguments[i]; ++i) { //arguments is automatic variable 
    //'this' is an alias of the newly created object 
    this[arg] = arg; //or whatever which depends on the arg
  }
}

var titles = new myTitles('a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2');//create a new object with properties. 'new' is required.
console.log(titles);
console.log(titles.a1);



